# How do you configure java.home property in play's application.conf?

Tags: scala, playframework

Some of the [play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/KeyStores#Configuring-a-Trust-Manager) references a `${java.home}` variable, but it is not defined by default.

> Could not resolve substitution to a value: ${java.home}

Is there a better way to access this variable without hard-coding it eg:

```
java.home = "/some/path/to/java_home"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply try this:
`java.home = ${JAVA_HOME}`